# Order Matching sequence going opposite with Java + Spring + Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, trading

I have developed an order matching service and it is functional (staging server). The logic implementation of executing the orders is working fine.

But there is a minute issue that has been bugging me and my colleague from almost a month. To explain it in a little more detail, please see the example of an orderbook below:

```
    Buy Side
    Qty 1 Price 3
    Qty 1 Price 2
    Qty 1 Price 1
```

These are existing order on the buy side. Now if a Seller comes and places the sell order of 3 Qty @ Price 1/- all three buy orders should execute.

This functionality is running perfectly fine. The problem is with execution sequence. Ideally, the code should FIRST match the order with Price 3, then 2, and then 1.

But it is executing in reverse order. Because of this the latest price is also coming wrong, and so does Net Change, and Net % growth. This sequence effects at lot of places.

It isn't possible to post entire code, so I am posting the part of the code that I ASSUME to have a problem.

```
    if (matchOrderRequest.getOrderType() == OrderType.BUY) {
    optionalMatchOrder=orderRepository.findTopByMarketAndOrderTypeAndPriceLessThanEqualOrderByPriceAscTimestampAsc(request.getMarket(), OrderType.SELL, request.getPrice());
    } 

    else {

    optionalMatchOrder = 
    orderRepository.findTopByMarketAndOrderTypeAndPriceGreaterThanEqualOrderByPriceDescTimestampAsc(request.getMarket(),OrderType.BUY,request.getPrice());

    }

    if (optionalMatchOrder.isPresent()) {

    executedOrder.setOrderId(request.getOrderId());
```

Order Repository (Mongo Query):

```
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.Optional;

    @Repository
    public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<MatchOrder, Long> {


Optional<MatchOrder> findTopByMarketAndOrderTypeAndPriceGreaterThanEqualOrderByPriceAscTimestampAsc(Market market, OrderType orderType, BigDecimal bigDecimal);


Optional<MatchOrder> findTopByMarketAndOrderTypeAndPriceGreaterThanEqualOrderByPriceDescTimestampAsc(Market market, OrderType orderType, BigDecimal bigDecimal);
```

Comment: Post your mongo queries as well.

Comment: Updated question with repository code.

Comment: Anyone to my help ???